# Why isn't Vue.js updating a child component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am using a child component for my header/navbar. This child component is named Header.vue.
I am importing it from the App.vue component like this:

```
<template>
  <div id="app" class="container">
    <navbar></navbar> 
  </div>
</template>

 <script>
 import navbar from './Header.vue'

   export default {
  name: 'app',
  firebase: {
    items: itemsRef
  },

  data () {
    return {
      newItem: {
        title: '',
        author: '',
        year: ''
      }
    }
  },
components: { 
    navbar
    }
  </script>
```

My child component (Header.vue) script goes like this:

```
<template>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
            <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <div class="navbar-right test">
            <a href="#">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>
            </a>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Sign in</button>
        </div>
    </nav>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'navbar',
  data () {
    return {
      username: 'joao'
    }
  }
}

</script>
```

The main component updates but the Header.vue doesn't.
It was working just fine but now it seems to be stuck at an earlier version of my header.vue component and it doesn't update. I am using webpack and `npm run dev` from the terminal to start the server. I have tried cleaning my cache with no results. I am just starting with vue.js so I am puzzled.
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Possibly unrelated, but you're missing a closing tag for your `<div>` in your `App.vue` file.

Comment: thanks John, I've corrected that now on the question – but that was a lapse that happened when I edited down my code to pose the question here. that's not the cause.

Comment: What do you expect to see happen?

Comment: Hi Bert, I am not doing any "dynamic" change. I just want to preview the header.vue template which is just a simple navbar "skeleton". I will add some more code to it now so you can see it.

Comment: Here is a working example (without firebase). https://codesandbox.io/s/44njx7klx

Comment: Many thanks Bert, but unfortunately I can see no difference between the example code you made and the one I have. Could firebase be causing this? I can't see why it would though.

Comment: I would check for errors in the console. Beyond that, start removing things and get to a working version, then add them back in and see what breaks it.

Comment: No errors on the console. I will try that. Many thanks.

Comment: I think I have figured it out. Wrong path to the child component... so I changed from
`import navbar from './components/Header.vue'`
to
`import navbar from './Header.vue'`
and its working.
I was weird it was showing an older version of my file though. Can't really understand why it was doing that.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have figured it out. Wrong path to the child component... so I changed from `import navbar from './components/Header.vue'` to `import navbar from './Header.vue'` and it's working. I was weird it was showing an older version of my file though. Can't really understand why it was doing that.